# Any benefit to fork repo when I have write access?

Tags: git, github

I have write access to someone's GitHub repository (I'm a collaborator). Is there any benefit for me in working it? I'm not that familiar with GitHub so I'm not sure if I'm losing anything by not forking and just using the original repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly organizational.

Some reasons you still might want to fork:

1. Your write access may be taken away
2. You might disagree with where the project is going
3. Too many people working on it already (too many branches, too much activity, too many notifications)
4. You want to experiment with major project-wide changes
5. You don't want to make the mistake of accidentally merging changes on a busy/official project
6. You believe your repo url will survive longer than the current "official" one and you don't want your apps to break
7. There are other people with access who you don't trust
8. You don't trust the original repository to stay compatible with your apps (or support legacy features, etc).
9. You want to separately keep track of your own issues/wiki
10. You have too many branches of your own and you prefer to merge to "master", even if that's not useful for the official repo.
11. You don't like the repo's restrictions/policies/hooks/triggers/configuration

In any case, if you have a fork that isn't official - make sure you say that in the description (so people know where to get "official" updates from, where to post issues, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The [Fork and Pull](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) is usually adopted when you don't have write access to a given repository. This is the case when contributing to projects which you haven't been deemed a maintainer/team member.

As a developer I don't see why you would fork a repository if you have access to create branches in the original repository. You should still follow the [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) or something similar regardless if you have write access or not.

In the end it's up to you, but if you have write access I would do branch and pull request.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation. I was randomly forking every project on GitHub to make my GitHub profile looks better 